# Is this code vulnerable to sql injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is this code prone to SQL Injection? Can you suggest something to improve the security? Is it right to use mysqli_real_escape_string? And do you think it's alright to use this for project?

```
<?php
require 'db.php';

    if(isset($_POST['pawnshopName'])&&isset($_POST['street'])&&isset($_POST['barangay'])&&isset($_POST['city'])&&isset($_POST['dtiPermitNo'])&&isset($_POST['mayorPermitNo'])&&isset($_POST['firstName'])&&isset($_POST['lastName'])&&isset($_POST['middleName'])&&isset($_POST['contactNumber'])&&isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['password'])&&isset($_POST['confirmPassword']))
{
    $options = ['cost' => 11, 'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),];
    $pawnshopName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['pawnshopName']);
    $street = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['street']);
    $barangay = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['barangay']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['city']);
    $dtiPermitNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['dtiPermitNo']);
    $mayorPermitNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['mayorPermitNo']);
    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['lastName']);
    $middleName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['middleName']);
    $contactNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['contactNumber']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options));
    $confirmPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['confirmPassword']);
    if(password_verify($confirmPassword,$password))
    {
        echo 'Password Match';
    }else
    {
        echo 'Password mismatch';
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pawnshop ".
    "(Pawnshop_ID, Pawnshop_Name, Street, Barangay, City, DTI_Permit_No, Mayor_Permit_No, Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Contact_Number, Email_Address, Password) ".
    "VALUES ".
    "('','".$pawnshopName."', '".$street."', '".$barangay."', '".$city."', '".$dtiPermitNo."', '".$mayorPermitNo."', '".$firstName."', '".$lastName."', '".$middleName."', '".$contactNumber."', '".$email."', '".$password."' )";

    mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    mysqli_close($connection);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must use `prepare` method. Then on every place where you want to add a value place a `?`. Than you must use the `bind_param` method. Finally, you can execute it and get the results whit `get_results`. An example:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Address, CityID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam('ssi', $name, $address, $cityId);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->get_results();
```

The `'ssi'` are corresponding variable the types of the attributes.

- `i` are integers
- `d` are doubles
- `s` are strings
- `b` is a blob and will be sent in packets

<sup>My resources are: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)</sup>

Comment: Do you know some resources where to study those method you have suggested? =)